# Problem with memory limit using wget mirror

Tags: memory, wget, mirror

I am trying to convert a dynamic site into a static one using the mirroring function of wget.
This one seems to work well, but as it is a very heavy site with many pages, I ran the command on `screen` and let it run for a few days.
Running a daily check, I noticed that my function was being killed as it was consuming too much memory.

After running the following command:

```
 wget -r -mirror --tries=1  --wait=1 --html-extension -o log http://mysite.tld
```

I have seen these errors into `/var/log/messages`:

```
kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 10645 (wget) score 367 or sacrifice child
kernel: Killed process 10645 (wget), UID 0, total-vm:3154656kB, anon-rss:624672kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

I launch the command on a centos7 VPS with 4GB of RAM and 4vCPU (site hosting vps) and the command seems to saturate all available memory in maximum 2 days.

Is there any way to limit the memory consumption of the command launched, or to make it so that when it dies it restarts from where it was killed?

Comment: @Panki yes sorry